# Caking routes and url rewriting

Tags: url, cakephp, url-rewriting, routes, cakephp-1.2

I have my routes declared like this:

```
    Router::connect('/profile/', array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'profile')); 
    Router::connect('/accounts/:action/*', array('controller' => 'accounts'));
    Router::connect('/:username', array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'profile'), array('pass' => array('username')));
```

All my links are made with Cake's $html->url api call.  The routes work fine when the url is just [domain]/accounts/profile and it gets rewritten correctly as [domain]/profile.

But when I make a link using $html->url(array('controller'=>'accounts', 'action'=>'profile', $username), true), the url write is [domain]/accounts/profile/:username and not just [domain]/:username.

How do I make it [domain]/:username?

Answer (score 1):

try like so

```
Router::connect('/:username', array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'profile'), array('pass' => array('username')));
Router::connect('/profile/', array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'profile')); 
Router::connect('/accounts/:action/*', array('controller' => 'accounts'));
```